# What is the difference between matrixpower() and markov() when it comes to computing P^n?

Tags: r, matrix, markov-chains

Consider a Markov chain with state space `S = {1, 2, 3, 4}` and transition matrix

```
P =  0.1  0.2  0.4  0.3
     0.4  0.0  0.4  0.2
     0.3  0.3  0.0  0.4
     0.2  0.1  0.4  0.3
```

And, take a look at the following source code:

```
# markov function
markov <- function(init,mat,n,labels) 
{ 
    if (missing(labels)) 
    {
        labels <- 1:length(init) 
    }

    simlist <- numeric(n+1) 
    states <- 1:length(init) 
    simlist[1] <- sample(states,1,prob=init)  

    for (i in 2:(n+1))
    { 
        simlist[i] <- sample(states, 1, prob = mat[simlist[i-1],])  
    }

    labels[simlist] 
}

# matrixpower function
matrixpower <- function(mat,k) 
{
    if (k == 0) return (diag(dim(mat)[1])) 
    if (k == 1) return(mat)
    if (k > 1) return( mat %*% matrixpower(mat, k-1))
}

tmat = matrix(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3,
                0.4, 0.0, 0.4, 0.2,
                0.3, 0.3, 0.0, 0.4,
                0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

p10 = matrixpower(mat = tmat, k=10)  
rowMeans(p10)

nn <- 10 
alpha <- c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)

set.seed(1)

steps <- markov(init=alpha, mat=tmat, n=nn)
table(steps)/(nn + 1)
```

**Output**

```
> rowMeans(p10)
[1] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
> 
.
.
.
> table(steps)/(nn + 1)
steps
         1          2          3          4 
0.09090909 0.18181818 0.18181818 0.54545455 
> ?rowMeans
```

Why are results so different?

What is the difference between using `matrixpower()` and `markov()` when it come to compute ***P<sup>n</sup>***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you are comparing completely different things. First, I'll focus not on computing P<sup>n</sup>, but rather A*P<sup>n</sup>, where A is the initial distribution. In that case `matrixpower` does the job:

```
p10 <- matrixpower(mat = tmat, k = 10)  
alpha <- c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)
alpha %*% p10
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.2376945 0.1644685 0.2857105 0.3121265
```

those are the true probabilities of being in states 1, 2, 3, 4, respectively, after 10 steps (after the initial draw made using A).

Meanwhile, `markov(init = alpha, mat = tmat, n = nn)` is only a single realization of length `nn + 1` and only the last number of this realization is relevant for A*P<sup>n</sup>. So, as to try to get similar numbers to the theoretical ones, we need many realizations with `nn <- 10`, as in

```
table(replicate(markov(init = alpha, mat = tmat, n = nn)[nn + 1], n = 10000)) / 10000
#
#      1      2      3      4 
# 0.2346 0.1663 0.2814 0.3177
```

where I simulate 10000 realizations and take only the last state of each realization.