# Markov Chain simulation, calculating limit distribution

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, markov-chains

I have a Markov Chain with states S={1,2,3,4} and probability matrix

P=(.180,.274,.426,.120)
  (.171,.368,.274,.188)
  (.161,.339,.375,.125)
  (.079,.355,.384,.182)

First,second,third,fourth row respectively.

Evaluating to different powers P, the limit distribution is (.155,.342,.351,.155)

Here is my approach to implement this in R using simulation:

```
f<-function(Nsim)
{

x<-numeric(Nsim)
x[1]=1 #the seed

ones<-numeric(1)
twos<-numeric(1)
thres<-numeric(1)
fours<-numeric(1)

for(i in 2:Nsim)
{
  if(x[i-1]==1)
    x[i]=sample(1:4,1,prob=c(.180,.274,.426,.120))
  if(x[i-1]==2)
    x[i]=sample(1:4,1,prob=c(.171,.368,.274,.188))
  if(x[i-1]==3)
    x[i]=sample(1:4,1,prob=c(.161,.339,.375,.125))
  if(x[i-1]==4)
    x[i]=sample(1:4,1,prob=c(.079,.355,.384,.182))

}
x

for(i in 1:Nsim)
{
  if(x[i]==1)
    ones<-ones+1
  if(x[i]==2)
    twos<-twos+1
  if(x[i]==3)
    thres<-thres+1
  else
    fours<-fours+1
}

prop1<-1/ones
prop2<-2/twos
prop3<-3/thres
prop4<-4/fours

list<-c(prop1,prop2,prop3,prop4)
return(list)
}
```

The code marks no errors, fortunately :), but it does not return what is expected with is `(.155,.342,.351,.155)`.

For example, `f(1000)` returns
`[1] 0.006993007 0.006172840 0.008620690 0.006134969`

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `prop1 <- ones/Nsim`, and so on.

Comment: oh right how I make such mistake.. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function correctly stores a single Markov chain realization of length `Nsim` to `x`, but then `prop1`, ..., `prop4` aren't really proportions of ones, ..., fours; they seem to be more related to the expected value in this whole chain. You also overestimate the number of fours, but @StéphaneLaurent's answer deals with that too.

Then, once fixed, your approach with a very large `Nsim` works because starting from, say, step 30 we are already close to the stationary distribution, and while the initial 30 values are "noisy", they become negligible with a large `Nsim`.

An alternative approach would be to focus on P<sup>k</sup> for some large and fixed k, which should be less efficient, but probably more intuitive. In particular, in that case we simulate *many* (for the law of large number to work) realizations of *relatively long* (as for something close to the limiting distribution to be at work) Markov chains. Also, the simulation can be written much more compactly. In particular, consider a generalization of my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55830847/1320535):

```
chainSim <- function(alpha, mat, n) {
  out <- numeric(n)
  out[1] <- sample(1:ncol(mat), 1, prob = alpha)
  for(i in 2:n)
    out[i] <- sample(1:ncol(mat), 1, prob = mat[out[i - 1], ])
  out
}
```

Now let's simulate 30000 chains of length 30, again starting from state 1, as in your case. This gives (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56079656/1320535))

```
set.seed(1)
k <- 30
n <- 30000
table(replicate(chainSim(c(1, 0, 0, 0), M, k), n = n)[k, ]) / n
#         1         2         3         4 
# 0.1557333 0.3442333 0.3490333 0.1510000
```

where

```
M
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] 0.180 0.274 0.426 0.120
# [2,] 0.171 0.368 0.274 0.188
# [3,] 0.161 0.339 0.375 0.125
# [4,] 0.079 0.355 0.384 0.182
```

with

```
M <- structure(c(0.18, 0.171, 0.161, 0.079, 0.274, 0.368, 0.339, 0.355, 
                 0.426, 0.274, 0.375, 0.384, 0.12, 0.188, 0.125, 0.182), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
```

In this way we approximate the stationary distribution using `n` observations of a state in the k-th step.

Comment: This is not very different: this is correct up to the corrections I give in my answer. It is not true that you have to use the uniform distribution  as the initial distribution: the limit distribution is independent of the initial distribution. But yes, the code can be highly improved (as you did).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, agreed and edited accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @Isa, since you already have proportions, it's `barplot` what you need rather than `hist` (for it you should instead provide the whole chain, `x`). E.g., `barplot(f(10000))`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in your code:

```
  for(i in 1:Nsim)
  {
    if(x[i]==1)
      ones<-ones+1
    else if(x[i]==2) # this 'else' was missing
      twos<-twos+1
    else if(x[i]==3) # this 'else' was missing
      thres<-thres+1
    else
      fours<-fours+1
  }

  prop1<- ones/Nsim # not 1/ones
  prop2<- twos/Nsim # not 2/twos
  prop3<- thres/Nsim # not 3/thres
  prop4<- fours/Nsim # not 4/fours
```